# Make an image appear at the center for mobile view using CSS

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have made a html page hich have the heading and logo code like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6" style="width:100%">
    <div class="widget text-center " style="margin-bottom: 60px">

      <div><img src="images/logo.jpg"  alt="BS" align="left" height=80px width=80px> </div>
      <h2 style="font-size: 29px">This is the best university in the  world</h2>
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to set the image at the center and the text inside `h2` tag below the image for screen size smaller than *992 px* wide but for all other screen size the text will appear beside the image. How will I do that using css?

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
    .parentDiv{
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .parentDiv img{
        text-align: left;
        height: 80px;
        width: 80px;
    }
    .heading{
        font-size: 29px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    @media only screen and (max-width: 992px) {
        /* For mobile phones: */
        .parentDiv{
            width: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
            text-align:  center;
        }
        .parentDiv img{
            text-align: center;
            height: 80px;
            width: 80px;
        }
        .heading{
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 29px;
            display: block;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-6" style="width:100%">
        <div class="widget text-center " style="margin-bottom: 60px;">
            <div class="parentDiv" ><img src="pexels.jpeg" alt="BS" > 
   </div>
            <div class="heading"><h2 style="">This is the best 
         university in the  
            world</h2></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: but for all other screen size >=992px, will the text appear beside the image? How will I do that using css? @Mohit Kumar Bordia

Answer (score 0):

I've provided a Codepen (URL below) which switches your styling out of the breakpoint, so that it is respected by all mobile devices. The breakpoint is now invoked on anything at and above 993px, so the image is now positioned (floated) to the left, and the text is positioned (floated) to the right of the image.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 993px) {
    /* For everything else: */
    .parentDiv {
        display: inline;
        width: auto;
    }
    .parentDiv img {
        float: left;
    }
    .heading {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

[Codepen] (https://codepen.io/sassquad/pen/zJRKYZ)